# How do I write the following ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have materials which:

- belong to a user: **user_id:**
- can be masters or versions: **status:**
- can have a parent_id if a version: **parent_id:** (note: if it's a master the parent_id will be nil)

I want to get all the materials that:

a) belong to a certain user
b) are not versions **unless the parent_id of the version is not one of the ids of the masters**

How would I do this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.
This will give you the master materials or (version materials that aren't childs of a master of the user) for a given user.

```
master_ids = certain_user.materials.where(status: 'master').pluck(:id)
certain_user.materials.where("status = ? OR parent_id NOT IN (?)", 'master', master_ids)
```

If you don't have access to an instance of the user just replace `certain_user.materials` with `Material.where(user_id: the_id_of_the_user)`

Answer (score 0):

Try these...

```
a)Material.joins(:users).merge(User.where(field: value))

b)Material.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL and parent_id not in (?)", Material.pluck(:id))
```